# Parsing json to Nattable

Tags: nattable

I have to parse a Json file and show it into a Nattable. 
Using [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTableDataSources/article.html) tutorial i am able to parse json and display in Nattable.[image]

But as shown in screenshot **for cat column** its showing list values as it is .
Is there a way from which i can show list values as Dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

A dropdown in NatTable is intended for editing. I suppose you don't want to support editing but only showing values right? For that you can try to use the `TableCellPainter` for that column. That painter tries to render the data as subcells in case the data structure is an array or a Collection.